# Validation rule with record types and alphanumeric

Tags: validation-rule, record-type

I need to create a validation rule with several criteria. When creating a new Example ID, the ID must be:

- Alphanumeric or alpha only
- If the record type is A, it must be 5 digits
- If the record type is B or C, it must be 6 digits

I am continuing to get errors and this is what I have tried so far, can someone help?

```
NOT(
    REGEX(ExampleID__c ,("[A-Za-z0-9 ]*"))
) 
AND(LEN(ExampleID__c) <> 5, RecordTypeId = "A") 
OR(LEN( ExampleID__c ) <> 6, RecordTypeId = "B",  RecordTypeId = "C")
```

Comment: If you're getting errors, you should always share them (exact text, verbatim).

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Yes, please help us to help you by giving details. One thing is for sure, though, you cannot just "stack" formula functions like that: `NOT() AND() OR()` - the entire field has to evaluate to one TRUE or FALSE. Plus "I do not think [`OR`] means what you think it means." There are many issues with your code, so I would suggest that you start with the individual Formula Functions themselves and make sure you are using them as they are programmed: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5.

Answer (score 2):

#### Some background

The root of your issues here are that you're not properly using `AND()` and `OR()`, which are not operators in your attempt but are rather *functions*.

There are boolean operators for "and" and "or" (`&&` and `||` respectively) which are binary (in that they take 2 arguments) and *infix* (i.e. you put the operator between the operands, `x && y`).

You *can* use the boolean operators, and it's syntactically valid to mix those with the boolean functions, but **you should pick one, and stick with it**. For what it's worth, I prefer `AND()` and `OR()` in formulas.

#### Syntax issues

The syntax problem you're running into here is that you're trying to treat `AND()` and `OR()` as a strange mix of both function and operator. `AND()` and `OR()` (and `NOT()` as well) only apply to the stuff inside of the parenthesis. To tie everything together, you need to wrap it all inside of another `AND()` or `OR()`.

Put more visually, if you use the infix boolean operators

```
(a && b) || (c && d)
```

The equivalent to that using the boolean functions would be

```
OR(
    AND(a, b),
    AND(c, d)
)
```

#### Hardcoding Ids

Hardcoding Ids is not good practice. I think I've seen Salesforce give advice in places to use Ids instead of names, but I can't find an official recommendation to that effect. Anyone giving you such advice is quite simply someone you should ignore.

It is true that record names (and names for things like record types) can change.

However, if you're developing things in a sandbox (as we all should be). The Ids for record types are *guaranteed* to change when you deploy them (between sandboxes, into a scratch org, or from a sandbox to prod). The record type Id only stabilizes once you get it into production and refresh sandboxes.

Between something that *can* change, and something that *will* change, it's obvious that we should avoid using the thing that will change.

So instead of `RecordTypeId = '<rectype id here>'`, use `RecordType.Name = '<rectype label here>` or `RecordType.DeveloperName = '<rectype_dev_name_here>`. DeveloperName = the API name, and it will have no spaces.

#### Putting it together

Figuring out whether to use `AND()` or `OR()` is always fun with validation rules because validation rules prevent records from being saved when the result is true. That routinely messes with my intuition as a developer.

Assuming that a non-alphanumeric string means the entire record is now invalid, you want to tie your 3 conditions together with an `OR()`.

Another hint that `OR()` is what you want to use is that you have conditions on the recordtype. Since recordtype can only hold one value, If you'd try something like `AND(AND(rectype 1, condition), AND(rectype2, condition))`, the result would always be false (because one of the two inner `AND()` would be guaranteed to result in false).

From there, the first two conditions look syntactically correct. The only real change you need to make is to the third condition.

`(x || y) && z` translates to `AND(OR(x, y), z)`

Also, be sure to [follow the Formula Best Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_formula_best_practices.htm&type=5)

- New function => give it it's own line
- ALLCAPS function names
- Indent

```
OR(
    /* The regex itself may need a bit more work, but this is syntactically correct */
    /* The extra parenthesis pair around the regex string does nothing for you */
    NOT(
        REGEX(ExampleID__c ,"[A-Za-z0-9 ]*")
    ),
    AND(
        RecordType.Name = 'some name A',
        LEN(ExampleID__c) <> 5
    ),
    AND(
        OR(
            RecordType.Name = 'some name B',
            RecordType.Name = 'other name C'
        ),
        LEN(ExampleID__c) <> 6
    )
)
```

Comment: Yes, I do break the "function on its own line" with `LEN()` guideline here. The overall goal is readability, and I think that `LEN(something) <> [integer here]` is easier to read than it would be if it were spread over 2 (or 3) lines.